# iOS Static Library with Image resources

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, resources, static-libraries

I have a static library where I need some graphics resources as Images.
In my class I would to add an image in this way:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
```

but it not work...
how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ..

I explored the bundles directory (compiled) and I've noticed that my images (`.png`) they had all the iestensione `.tiff`

To avoid this I set the key `HIDPI_COMBINE_IMAGES` in my bundle buid setting  as `NO`

..so I can recover my pictures as suggested by *e1985*

Comment: thanks. the actual flag is called COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES in case you're wondering.

Answer (score 2):

You can't provide anything other than code with a static library.  This is because `.a` files are a simple archive of object files, with the added ability under Mac/iOS of supporting multiple CPU architectures.

The only option you have is to create a Framework, which can provide code as well as other resources.

Comment: ok, I have created a bundle in my library for my resources, how do I use these resources? I followed this tutorial http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Comment: @GgSalent Looks like something of a hack to me and I'd argue that the resources are really part of the library at all; they may be in the same directory but that's all the library and the bundle share.  I've no idea how you use the resources within the bundle.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have that bundle, you can access to the resources you have there like this:

```
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourBundle" ofType:@"bundle"];
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image= [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Comment: Yes..but the image is nil..
I added my imge (for example myImage.png on my bundle resources) and I tested your way... but the image obj is nil! :(

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, if you link a static library, the code from the library is included directly into your executable. No files are copied to the application bundle, so there's no way to copy the image.

If you have the image file with your static library, you can simply copy it to your application bundle by adding a copy files build phase to your target in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Framework target, not static library.
Make sure "Copy Bundle Resources" exists in Build Phases for your Framework. Add your resource files there.

Then to find the file in the Framework bundle from an outside project I just do this:

```
NSArray<NSBundle *> * bundles = [NSBundle allFrameworks];
NSString * filePath;
for (int i = 0; i < bundles.count; i++) {

     filePath = [[bundles objectAtIndex:i] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"];
     if (filePath != nil) break; // found
}
```